# golang websocket server unable to send message as conenction is eastablished

Tags: go

```
type WebsocketServer struct {
    conn     *websocket.Conn
    ticker   time.Ticker
    wg       sync.WaitGroup
    stopChan chan interface{}
}

// SetupWebSocketRoutes sets up the routes for WebSocket connections.
func SetupWebSocketRoutes(app *fiber.App, ctx appcontext.ChannelContext, hub *WebsocketHub) {
    app.Use("/ws", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
            return c.Next()
        }
        return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
    })

    app.Get("/ws", websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {
        log.Println("WebSocket connection established")ac
        id, betChan := hub.RegisterClient()
        defer hub.UnregisterClient(id)
        log.Printf("Client registered with ID: %v", id)

        timer := time.NewTicker(8 * time.Second)
        defer timer.Stop()

        for {
            select {
            case bet, ok := <-betChan:
                if !ok {
                    log.Println("WebSocket connection closed due to channel closure")
                    c.Close()
                    return
                }
                log.Println("Received bet update from channel")
                msg, err := json.Marshal(bet)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error marshaling bet: %v", err)
                    continue
                }
                err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error writing message to WebSocket: %v", err)
                    c.Close()
                    return
                }
            case <-timer.C:
                log.Println("Sending ping message to WebSocket")
                err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, nil)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error writing ping message to WebSocket: %v", err)
                    c.Close()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }))
}

func PopulateBetUpdatesChannel(betUpdatesChan chan<- *models.Bet) {
    for {
        bet := &models.Bet{ // msg
        }

        betUpdatesChan <- bet

    }
}
```

its not sending the demo message i craeated below only ping message

what should i do to make the websocket server post the message also and client side to recieve the message properly the message is just demo just for now will be updated from a web service in the futuree

to get the mesg recieved from client server

Comment: I use structs to send the data over and then access the javascript json on the other side. I can post some code tomorrow but it doesn't follow the same model you've laid out above. `err := conn.WriteJSON(m)` on the server side and then: `var m = JSON.parse(event.data)` on the client side.